# Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

more specifically the error warning I ma getting is:

```
Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am currently creating a signup page that ask user to fill few specific details such as Name, Country, Email, Password and etc. To make sure user provide all the relevant information I am trying to write a code to send an alert if user does not provide all the information. I have wrote the code taking help from stakeoverflow.

Problem: Whenever user left any field blank it is not showing the alert and by default performing a segue that takes user to signin page. This is the first time I am creating an alert and hence don't what is going wrong (I believe 95% of my code is in place)

can anyone help?

```
     @IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if nameText.text!.isEmpty || genderText.text!.isEmpty || countryText.text!.isEmpty || yourSchool.text!.isEmpty || yourClass.text!.isEmpty {

        print("Please fill all fields") 

        //my code is printing above error in the Xcode console but the below code is not working 

        //setting error message if not all fiels filled
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please fill all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: yourEmail.text!, password: yourPassword.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {

                ///print errror message
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {

                print("You have successfully signed up")

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "JoinUs2SignPage", sender: self)

                //updating user information
                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                let usertype: String = "Student"
                self.ref.child("users").child(userID).setValue(["usertype": usertype ,"username": self.nameText.text!, "usergender": self.genderText.text!, "usercountry": self.countryText.text!, "userschool": self.yourSchool.text!, "userclass": self.yourClass.text!,])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tested this with break points? I mean there is no other code doing same thing or storyboard connection that performs segue?

Comment: Why is `yourSchool.text` checked twice?

Comment: @vadish twice here will not make the problem

Comment: @Sh_Khan And `== ""` and `.isEmpty` makes no difference.

Comment: @vadian it's buggy in swift

Comment: @Sh_Khan Buggy? Do you have a source for the predication?

Comment: my code is able to perform if condition perfectly fine as it is able to print the error i.e. print("Please fill all fields"). However, UIAlert part of the code is not working i.e. alert message is not popping up

Comment: @TusharSharma I didn’t your get question .. could you please explain it

Answer (score 0):

Action may be out of main thread

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {

  ///print errror message
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error",    message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

   let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
   alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

  self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Try this approach

check for white space like that

```
 let nameTrimmed = self.nameText.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

 let genderTrimmed = self.genderText.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

 let countryTrimmed = self.countryText.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

 let schoolTrimmed = self.schoolText.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)



 if  nameTrimmed.text == "" ||  genderTrimmed.text == "" ||   countryTrimmed.text == "" ||  schoolTrimmed.text == ""
```

Comment: I guess text fields have default value to "". So it will not treat it as empty, and this approach might not work.

Comment: Hi Sh_Khan, my code is able to perform if condition perfectly fine as it is able to print the error i.e. print("Please fill all fields"). However, UIAlert part of the code is not working i.e. alert message is not popping up

Comment: @ Sh_Khan thanks for the solution but its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if nameText.text!.isEmpty || genderText.text!.isEmpty || countryText.text!.isEmpty || yourSchool.text!.isEmpty || yourClass.text!.isEmpty {

        print("Please fill all fields") //my code is printing this error

        //alert message popup

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please fill all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        print("Okay")
        }))

        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
        alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    else {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: yourEmail.text!, password: yourPassword.text!) { (user, error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        ///print errror message

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                            print("Okay")
                        }))

                        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                        alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
                        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
                        alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
                        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }

                    else {

                        print("You have successfully signed up")

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "JoinUs2SignPage", sender: self)

                        //updating user information
                        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                        let usertype: String = "Student"
                        self.ref.child("users").child(userID).setValue(["usertype": usertype ,"username": self.nameText.text!, "usergender": self.genderText.text!, "usercountry": self.countryText.text!, "userschool": self.yourSchool.text!, "userclass": self.yourClass.text!,])
                        }
            }
        }

}
```